# Error message when trying to nickname someone using discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content.lower() # The actual content of the message in lowercase
    pattern = "imagine having a name as dumb as (.{0,32})" # Max length for nicks is 32 characters 

    if (nick := re.findall(pattern, content): # Walrus operator, need python 3.8+
        await message.author.edit(nick=nick[0]) # Editing the actual nick
```

I get this error:

```
File "main.py", line 75
    if (nick := re.findall(pattern, content):
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing paranthesis

```py
if (nick := re.findall(pattern, content)):
```

Comment: oh, how did I not notice that? well anyways, it still doesn't work, it says " [pyflakes] undefined name 're' "

Comment: you need to import it `import re`

Comment: oh there's no error but it still doesn't work

Comment: well then findall is returning empty tuple/ list

Comment: is there a way I can fix that?